# Remove row if contains specific string except one between rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML which looks like this:

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody id="number">
    <tr class="is-first">delete</tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It should be like this:

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody id="number">
    <tr class="is-first">delete</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>delete</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to remove entries row if contains specific string except one between rows. I need Javascript or jQuery code to solve this problem.

I tried this code but it removes all of the table.

```
$('.table tr:contains("delete")').parent().remove();
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want removed. You say "Remove entries row if contains specific string except one between row" Please tell us what your desired result is. do you want the rows with `-` removed or the element before it

Comment: Also `$('.table tr:contains("-")').parent().remove();` removes the `tbody`

Comment: First of, `<tr>` is not supposed to contain characters like `-`. So fix that, and then you can eventually ask a new question.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i want only one "-" between row but i dont know how to define it

Comment: I placed your HTML in runnable snippets - you can see it's invalid as all the `-` characters are appearing outside of the table. Can you please edit the question to correct your HTML. I'm assuming it's correct in your production version at least, due to the fact you say the `-` appear *between* rows.

Comment: real data is not "-" sir, it's constant string, never change but i replace it with "-" to easy to read

Comment: @DREAM Please run the first snippet, and inspect the code. You will see it changes becuase `<tr>-</tr>` or `<tr>DELETE</tr>` is not valid

Comment: Understood, but the problem is that you broke the HTML. It's nearly always better to include *the actual* code.

Comment: Your edit to change the `-` to the word `delete` is still invalid - the content in the `<tr>` *has to be within a `<td>` or `<th>`*

Comment: i add image in post just now

Comment: "delete" line is too many, i want only one line between row, that what i mean

Comment: would this not fix it `$('.table tr:contains("-")').remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said in comment,first you need to put text inside `td` instead of `tr`

For your question,the quick way is to filter the `tr` that needs to be deleted,then we delete it one by one

```js
let deleted =[]
$(".table > tbody > tr > td:contains('delete')").each((index,ele) =>{
  if($(ele).parent().prev().text()=="delete"){
     deleted.push(ele)
   }
})

deleted.forEach(e =>{
  $(e).remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" border="1">
        <tbody id="number">
        <tr class="is-first"><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123456789</td><td class="is-number">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123456789</td><td class="is-number">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123456789</td><td class="is-number">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123456789</td><td class="is-number">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i replace "delete" with <td colspan="2">delete</td> then use this code, it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes a correct table structure to start with. eg. `delete` should be wrapped in a `<td>` element. With that out of the way, let's get to the answer.

You can select all `<tr>` elements that contains `<td>delete</td>` with:

```js
$('tr:has(td:contains("delete"))')
```

If you only want to select `<tr>` elements that contains `<td>delete</td>`, that directly follow another `<tr>` element that contains `<td>delete</td>`. You can do so using the [adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

```js
$('tr:has(td:contains("delete")) + tr:has(td:contains("delete"))')
```

```js
function cleanTable() {
  $('tr:has(td:contains("delete")) + tr:has(td:contains("delete"))').remove();
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", cleanTable);
```

```css
td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<button type="button">clean table</button>

<table class="table">
  <tbody id="number">
    <tr class="is-first"><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456789</td>
      <td class="is-number">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">delete</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```